# AWK equivalent in windows batch script

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a file test.txt as

```
:ROOM1: :CITY: :2000:
:ROOM2: :RURAL: :1500:
:ROOM3: :CITY: :3000:
```

I need to get the last word based on the first and second word. I made it in Unix using AWK:

```
cat get_room_rent.ksh
#!/bin/ksh
FILE_NAME=test.ksh
awk -F: '{ if ($2 == room_name && $4 == type) {print $6} }' room_name=$1 type=$2 $ROOM_RENT
echo ${ROOM_RENT}
```

Running above script

```
RM_RNT=`./get_room_rent.ksh ROOM2 RURAL`
```

Output

```
1500
```

I need to make the same in a Windows batch file... I would not be installing an AWK Windows version.

I tried something like the below, but I had no luck...

```
FOR /F "tokens=%ROOM2% delims=:" %%G IN (C:test.txt) DO echo Chosen word is: %%G&goto nextline
:nextline

set showme=Y
FOR /F "tokens=%ROOM2% delims=:" %%G IN (c:test.txt) DO if defined showme set showme=&echo Chosen word is: %%G
```

Comment: "*I would not be installing awk windows version*" - why not? Seems much easier to me. You can download ZIP files with awk for windows that don't require any installation, e.g. here: http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I can't do that.. its a restricted server and need to manage what it has in default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cmd
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "ROOM_RENT=data.txt"

    rem Option 1 - First filter the contents
    for /f "tokens=5 delims=:" %%a in ('
        findstr /r /c:"^:%~1:[^:]*:%~2:" "%ROOM_RENT%"
    ') do echo %%a

    rem Option 2 - Iterate the file checking the fields
    for /f "usebackq tokens=1,3,5 delims=:" %%a in ("%ROOM_RENT%") do (
        if "%%~a"=="%~1" if "%%~b"=="%~2" echo %%~c
    )
```

Calling the batch file with `get_room_rent.cmd ROOM2 RURAL` you will retrieve the required information.

`for /f` command splits the records using the indicated characters as delimiters. Once the records have been split, the `tokens` clause indicates the list of tokens (the index of each token) to retrieve.

In the first option, the only token retrieved is the fifth one, as the lines are filtered to only retrieve the ones that matches. In the second case the three involved tokens are retrieved to handle the testing.

Why do the number of tokens not match those in the AWK code? The delimiter handling in `for /f` discards starting delimiters at the start of the line, from here the numbering difference. The initial `:` is discarded, and room name becomes the first field in the record.

Comment: +1, but you might mention that adding `/i` to the `findstr` and `if` statements can allow case-insensitive matching.

Comment: @rojo, the `awk` code in the question is case sensitive. Batch code is only replicating the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you're mistaken about the syntax of the `tokens` argument in a `for /f` loop.  That value is supposed to be numeric, and determines how many columns to skip before populating `%%G`.

Although this wouldn't be nearly as efficient as awk, the simplest solution would be to pipe `find` or `findstr` into `findstr` -- once for each argument.

```js
for /f "tokens=3" %%I in (
    'findstr /i "%~1" "test.txt" ^| findstr /i "%~2"'
) do set "showme=%%I"

if defined showme echo Chosen word is %showme::=%
```

I think that'll work anyway.  I haven't tested it.  Call it as `batfile.bat room2 rural`.  If you'd rather the searching be case-sensitive, remove the `/i` switches from the `findstr` commands.

Answer (score 0):

IMO PowerShell is a better solution. Here is one way:

```
param($s1, $s2)
get-content "test.txt" | foreach-object {
  $row = ($_ -split ' ') -replace ':',''
  if ( ($s1 -eq $row[0]) -and ($s2 -eq $row[1]) ) {
    $row[2]
  }
}
```